# How to encode Swift Arithmetic Operator Plus Sign (+) to utf8 data properly?

Tags: ios, swift, encoding, urlsession, moya

I m facing a situation where i need to encode a phone number with country code (like : +959450044651).And add it to a post request body and make a request.after than i face its not encoded property and its seems send string with an empty string for exaample "+959450044651" . how can fix this ?

here is my encoding code

```
let parameters = "phone=+959450044651"
var postData =  parameters.data(using: .utf8)
```

i get number with and empty space like :- " 959450044651"

but i need with + Like :- "+959450044651"

[image]

Comment: Did you debug the value before making a request? Please share all related code snipped. This values in screenshot seems not related to swift encoding directly.

Comment: thanks for response , yeah i debug it print request body before request i saw here is all ascii value printinig ok .I mean its prining  43 for  7th position (the plus) sign so its seem ok ..112
      - 104
      - 111
      - 110
      - 101
      - 61
      - 43
      - 57
      - 53
      - 57
      - 52
      - 53
      - 48
      - 48
      - 52
      - 52
      - 54
      - 53
      - 49

Comment: What do you do with "postData"? Do you directly attach it as the body of a request? What does your server do with the request's body?

Comment: You need to percent encode the plus sign

Comment: Try replacing “+” with “%2b”

Comment: I encoded the data (parameter data ) than directly attached to request http body like : request.httpBody = postData. and yes i Need to send + sign also.

Comment: @LeoDabus thank you its working fine .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to percent encode the plus sign. Just replace its occurrences with "%2b". Note that when converting a string to utf8 data it will never fail so you can simply pass its UTF8View `utf8` property to the `Data` initializer:

```
let parameters = "phone=+959450044651"
let postData =  Data(parameters.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2b").utf8)
```